# Has anyone had any difficulty upgrading from Entity Framework 1 to Entity framework 4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm looking at a project that has been developed and maintained with Entity Framework 1 that is relatively stable at this point.  I'm wondering if people have ever migrated a project like that to EF 4 and if anyone can share any particular difficulties they may have had.  I know there are a lot of benefits to look forward to but I'm trying to assess the risk involved if I upgrade.  Will it create a lot of unexpected behavior for someone who is accustomed to EF 1? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the only significant problem I've had.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544639/ef4-inheritance-defined-using-queryview-doesnt-work-properly-with-associations) It may or may not affect you. There's a workaround, but it's annoying.

If you're using pregenerated views you'll need to manually change your build events to use the .NET 4.0 EdmGen.